# Javascript error when using updatepanel

Tags: c#, telerik

I am new to telerik control. I am upgrading gridview to radgrid.

I am getting error (see image 1.JPG)(http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a851a8525e.jpg) when i am using radgrid in asp:updatepanel control. am getting this error foreveryaction(like sorting, filtering, editing, row selecting, scrolling). Can anyone help me how to sove this.

I have a linkbutton column in radgrid. when i click the button i am getting error( see image 2.JPG)(http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?ebbdac443a.jpg). How to do it in radgrid. I just want to pull sId, orderId, and taskstatus when i clicked on a linkbutton. when i am trying to do this i am getting that error. Please help to solve this.

here is my code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel  ID="rg200UpdatePanel"  runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
                        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
                        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
                            <ClientEvents OnRequestStart="onRequestStart" />
                            <AjaxSettings>
                                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rg200">
                                    <UpdatedControls>
                                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rg200" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadMenu1" />
                                    </UpdatedControls>
                                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadMenu1">
                                    <UpdatedControls>
                                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rg200" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadMenu1" />
                                    </UpdatedControls>
                                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                            </AjaxSettings>
                        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
                        <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Skin="Default">
                        </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
                        <input type="hidden" id="radGridClickedRowIndex" name="radGridClickedRowIndex" />
                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="rg200" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="30"
                            Height="550px" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="True"
                            EnableHeaderContextMenu="True" GridLines="None" EnableHeaderContextFilterMenu="True"
                            AllowMultiRowEdit="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" OnPreRender="rg200_PreRender"
                            OnItemCreated="rg200_ItemCreated" EnableViewState="true" OnUpdateCommand="rg200_UpdateCommand"
                            AllowAutomaticDeletes="false" AllowAutomaticInserts="false" AllowAutomaticUpdates="false"
                            OnPageIndexChanged="rg200_PageIndexChanged" OnItemCommand="rg216_ItemCommand">
                            <HeaderStyle Height="20px" BackColor="#004000" Font-Size="8pt" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"
                                HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" />
                            <ExportSettings IgnorePaging="true" ExportOnlyData="true">
                                <Pdf AllowModify="false" AllowPrinting="true" PageBottomMargin="" PageFooterMargin=""
                                    PageHeaderMargin="" PageHeight="11in" PageLeftMargin="" PageRightMargin="" PageTopMargin=""
                                    PageWidth="14in" />
                            </ExportSettings>
                            <MasterTableView GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="orderId" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                                EditMode="EditForms">
                                <CommandItemTemplate>
                                    <div style="padding: 5px 5px;">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr class="customFont">
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <b>Bulk Actions</b>    
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEditSelected" runat="server" OnClick="btnEditSelected_click"
                                                        Visible='<%# rg200.EditIndexes.Count == 0 %>'>Edit Selected</asp:LinkButton>

                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdateEdited" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpdateEdited_click"
                                                        Visible='<%# rg200.EditIndexes.Count > 0 %>'>Update Editing</asp:LinkButton>

                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" OnClick="btnCancel_click" Visible='<%# rg200.EditIndexes.Count > 0 || rg200.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted %>'>Cancel Editing</asp:LinkButton>

                                                </td>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    <img style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;" alt="" src="Images/AddRecord.gif" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="InitInsert" Visible='<%# !rg200.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted %>'>Add New Record</asp:LinkButton>

                                                </td>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    <img style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;" alt="" src="Images/Delete.gif" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Delete all selected Records?')"
                                                        runat="server" CommandName="DeleteSelected">Delete Selected</asp:LinkButton>

                                                </td>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    <img style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;" alt="" src="Images/Refresh.gif" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CommandName="Rebind">Refresh</asp:LinkButton>

                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ExportToWordButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ExportToWord.gif"
                                                        ToolTip="Export to Word" OnClick="ExportWord_Click" />

                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ExportToExcelButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ExportToExcel.gif"
                                                        ToolTip="Export to Excel" OnClick="ExportExcel_Click" />

                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ExportToPdfButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ExportToPdf.gif"
                                                        ToolTip="Export to Pdf" OnClick="ExportPdf_Click" />

                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ExportToCsvButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ExportToCsv.gif"
                                                        ToolTip="Export to Csv" OnClick="ExportCsv_Click" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </CommandItemTemplate>
                                <Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn" HeaderStyle-Width="3%"
                                        ItemStyle-Width="3%">
                                        <HeaderStyle Width="3%"></HeaderStyle>
                                        <ItemStyle Width="3%"></ItemStyle>
                                    </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="sId" HeaderText="sId" DataField="sId" ReadOnly="true"
                                        Visible="false">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="orderId" HeaderText="orderId" Visible="false"
                                        ReadOnly="true" DataField="orderId">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Customer Name" HeaderText="Customer Name" DataField="Customer Name"
                                        ReadOnly="true">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Market Name" HeaderText="Market Name" DataField="Market Name"
                                        ReadOnly="true">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="LOB" HeaderText="LOB" DataField="LOB" ReadOnly="true">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Headend Name" HeaderText="Headend Name" DataField="Headend Name"
                                        ReadOnly="true">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Project Name" HeaderText="Project Name" DataField="Project Name"
                                        ReadOnly="true">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Site Name" HeaderText="Site Name" DataField="SiteName"
                                        ReadOnly="true">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSiteName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval( "Site Name" ) %>'
                                                ForeColor="Blue" CommandName="sitename"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Task Status" HeaderText="Task Status" DataField="Task Status"
                                        ReadOnly="true">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Clarify Account Nbr" HeaderText="Clarify Account Nbr"
                                        DataField="Clarify Account Nbr">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Site ID" HeaderText="Site ID" DataField="Site ID">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Quote ID" HeaderText="Quote ID" DataField="Quote ID">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn UniqueName="EDP Created?" HeaderText="EDP Created?" DataField="EDP Created?">
                                    </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" Visible="false" Display="false">
                                    </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                                </Columns>
                                <EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
                                    <FormTemplate>
                                        <table id="Table1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <telerik:RadTabStrip runat="server" ID="RadTabStrip1" Orientation="HorizontalTop"
                                                        SelectedIndex="0" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1">
                                                        <Tabs>
                                                            <telerik:RadTab Text="Task Data" PageViewID="RadPageView1">
                                                            </telerik:RadTab>
                                                            <telerik:RadTab Text="Notes" PageViewID="RadPageView2">
                                                            </telerik:RadTab>
                                                        </Tabs>
                                                    </telerik:RadTabStrip>
                                                    <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0">
                                                        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView1">
                                                            <table id="Table3" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="250" border="0" class="module">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        Clarify Account Nbr:
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval( "Clarify Account Nbr" ) %>'>
                                                                        </asp:TextBox>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        Site ID:
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval( "Site ID") %>' TabIndex="1">
                                                                        </asp:TextBox>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        Quote ID:
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval( "Quote ID") %>' TabIndex="2">
                                                                        </asp:TextBox>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        EDP Created?:
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval( "EDP Created?") %>' TabIndex="3">
                                                                        </asp:CheckBox>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                                                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "Insert" : "Update" %>'
                                                                            runat="server" CommandName='Update'></asp:Button> 
                                                                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                                                            CommandName="Cancel"></asp:Button>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </telerik:RadPageView>
                                                        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView2">
                                                        </telerik:RadPageView>
                                                    </telerik:RadMultiPage>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </FormTemplate>
                                </EditFormSettings>
                            </MasterTableView>
                            <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" ReorderColumnsOnClient="false" AllowDragToGroup="false"
                                AllowColumnsReorder="True">
                                <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" EnableVirtualScrollPaging="false" UseStaticHeaders="true" />
                                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true"></Selecting>
                                <Resizing AllowRowResize="true" AllowColumnResize="True" EnableRealTimeResize="True"
                                    ResizeGridOnColumnResize="False"></Resizing>
                                <ClientEvents OnRowContextMenu="RowContextMenu" OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick"></ClientEvents>
                            </ClientSettings>
                            <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" AlwaysVisible="true"></PagerStyle>
                        </telerik:RadGrid>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.cs file

```
protected void rg216_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName.ToLower() == "sitename")
        {
            GridViewRow rw = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            Label lblsId = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblsId");
            Label lblorderId = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblorderId");
            Label lblTaskStatus = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblTaskStatus");
            //Label lblsId = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblsId");
            //Label lblorderId = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblorderId");
            //Label lblTaskStatus = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTaskStatus");
            Session["selorderID"] = lblorderId.Text.Trim();
            Session["selsID"] = lblsId.Text;
            Session["selTaskStatus"] = lblTaskStatus.Text;
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.rg200UpdatePanel, this.GetType(), "strSearSiteName", "document.getElementById('ctl00_PagePlaceholder_ifrmPopups').src='OrdDet.aspx'", true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.rg200UpdatePanel, this.GetType(), "open", "openpopup()", true);
            ifrmPopups.Style.Add("height", "409px");
            LinkButton lnkSiteName = (LinkButton)rw.FindControl("lnkSiteName");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move all Telerik controls outside of the MS UpdatePanel and ajaxify them using merely he ajax manager. Placing RadScriptManager or asp ScriptManager inside update panel is not right as well.

Dick